# Pandas error "has no attribute sort_values" sorting a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Panda version is 1.3.5 and I am running into an error when I am trying to use the `sort_values` function.

**code**

```
founded_edvideos_list = find_matching_posts_forupdate(video_id_list, stop_at_page=stop_at_page)
founded_edvideos_df = pd.DataFrame(founded_edvideos_list)
founded_edvideos_df = pd.sort_values(by=['post_id'], ascending=True)
```

The last line gives an error

`getattr__ raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'") AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'sort_values'`

When I print the dataframe, it looks like the following, so I should be able to use the `post_id`.  I have checked the documentation and can't seem to find my issue.

**dataframe**

```
post_id                                         title  ...      vid_type vid_record
0    12994              Trailblazer Melba Pattillo Beals  ...  [6923, 6926]     [6929]
1    12992                         Trailblazer Asha Prem  ...        [6923]     [6929]
2    12894  Trailblazers Melisa Mujanovic and Nina Nukic  ...  [6923, 6926]     [6929]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `pandas.sort_values` instead of calling `sort_values` on an instance of `pandas.Dataframe`. Your sorting line should likely be:
`founded_edvideos_df = founded_edvideos_df.sort_values(by=['post_id'], ascending=True)`

Comment: Duh.  Thank you so much.  I see now.  I wasn't calling the frame.